# Hiding multiple buttons with one button click Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, ibaction

I am trying to hide two buttons when I press one button on the ViewController. I can only seem to hide the button I click but using `[sender setHidden:YES];`. The buttons I have:

```
- (IBAction)Button1:(UIButton*)sender;

- (IBAction)Button2:(UIButton*)sender;
```

I can't seem to use `Button2.hidden = YES` in Button1. Is there a way round this?

Comment: take global variable for `UIButton` and hide them, in selector

Answer (score 2):

You should create button property in your viewController, and use it to hide button:

```
@interface ViewController ()

  @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* button1;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* button2;

- (IBAction)action1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)action2:(id)sender;

@end
```

In the actions:

```
- (void)setButtonsHidden:(BOOL)hidden
{
   _button1.hidden = hidden;
   _button2.hidden = hidden;
}

#pragma mark Actions
- (IBAction)action1:(id)sender
{
    [self setButtonsHidden:YES];
}

- (IBAction)action2:(id)sender
{
   [self setButtonsHidden:YES];
}
```

Also you can use NSArray to store all buttons references:

```
@interface ViewController ()

   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray* allButtons;
   <.....>
```

In setButtonsHidden: method:

```
- (void)setButtonsHidden:(BOOL)hidden
{
    [_allButtons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    obj.hidden = hidden;
    }];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Viewcontroller.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)button2:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender
{
    _button1.hidden = YES;
    _button2.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)button2:(UIButton *)sender
{
    _button1.hidden = YES;
    _button2.hidden = YES;
}
```